# Incompatible two void functions declaration

Tags: c++, oop, templates, declaration

I have a problem about declaring two void functions in my template "Wallet" class, which are going to remove and add existing template class "CreditCard" to the vector. Compiler writes that "declaration is incompatible"

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include"CreditCard.h"
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Wallet
{
protected: 
    vector<CreditCard<T>>cards;
public:
    Wallet(vector<CreditCard<T>>cards);
    void addCreditCard(const CreditCard card);
    void removeCreditCard(const CreditCard card);
};

template<class T>
Wallet<T>::Wallet(vector<CreditCard<T>>cards) {

}

template<class T>
void Wallet<T>::addCreditCard(const CreditCard card) {
    
}

template<class T>
void Wallet<T>::removeCreditCard(const CreditCard card) {

}
```

Comment: You missed the `<T>` parameter in `const CreditCard card`

Comment: Off-topic, but you really should be passing types like `std::vector` by reference, not by value:  `Wallet(const std::vector<CreditCard<T>>& cards)`.  Passing by-value incurs an (unnecessary) copy of the parameter.

Comment: Unless the intent is to take ownership of the vector in which case passing by value makes sense and passing by references risks the extra copy. Which, looks like the intention here, though without the code filled in, it could end up being done incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **problem** is that `CreditCard` is a class template which is different from a **class-type**. So we have to specify the template argument list to make it a type.

To **solve** this you can specify the template arguments to `CreditCard` as shown below:

```
template<class T>
class Wallet
{
protected: 
    vector<CreditCard<T>>cards;
public:
    Wallet(vector<CreditCard<T>>cards);
//-------------------------------------vvv------------>specify template argument explicitly
    void addCreditCard(const CreditCard<T> card);
//----------------------------------------vvv------------>specify template argument explicitly
    void removeCreditCard(const CreditCard<T> card);
};
template<class T>
//--------------------------------------------vvv---------->specify template argument
void Wallet<T>::addCreditCard(const CreditCard<T> card) {
    
}

template<class T>
//-----------------------------------------------vvv---------->specify template argument
void Wallet<T>::removeCreditCard(const CreditCard<T> card) {

}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/3DLO-lGsg).